# Virtualbox fails to connect due to Windows Firewall, Vagrant cannot start

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, windows-firewall, vagrant-windows

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 Vagrant box that I am trying to use on a Windows 10 host.

The box is not the issue as it works fine on other systems.

My Virtualbox version is currently 5.1.28, I tried the latest version which is when the problem started so I rolled back to 5.1.28 hoping that would fix it, to no avail.

My Vagrant version is 2.0.0.

This is what I get when I run `vagrant up`

```
λ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'dev_box'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: Dev_default_1512943736797_96012
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 (guest) => 3000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

I thought this might be a Firewall issue, so I disabled the Firewall, but am still seeing the same issue.

How can I get Virtualbox/Vagrant to work on Windows 10?

**EDIT: The issue was that Windows Firewall had closed ports that were previously open on my system before I updated to the Fall Creators Update, specifically in this case port 22. I created an exception to allow that port 22 through, now it works as expected.**

Answer (score 2):

Running Windows7 I ran into the same problem.
Try this recomendation on superuser.com

https://superuser.com/questions/936581/how-to-config-windows-firewall-so-vm-host-only-can-ping-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I think Virtualization is not enabled on your BIOS.

Check that in: task manager > Performance tab> Virtualization
or through *systeminfo* from CMD

If *disabled*:

Check out how to enable it from BIOS, based on your hardware make.

If *enabled*:

Then try disabling "Hyper-V" from "Add or remove windows features"

You can also try to launch a 64 bit vm manually from Virtualbox, this may tell you the reason behind machine being in "unknown state"

Also, try creating a Vagrant File with following config (with 32 bit OS):

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  config.vm.box_download_insecure = true #true just to bypass ssl validation error (strict no for production)
end
```

Try running `vagrant up` from same directory.

Comment: I actually just now found the source of the problem. Windows Firewall closed ports that were previously open on my system prior to installing the Fall Creators Update. I opened port 22 for SSH and now it works.